# navbar submenu pushes content down

Tags: html, css, position

I have a navpar made by css but when show the navbar sub menu it pushes the content underneath down

This is a link to codepen with full code
https://codepen.io/muhamedhashem/pen/GqNQaE

image 
[image]

html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title> </title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
    <div class="nav">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">One</a></li>


            <li>
                <a href="#">
                    Two
                    <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-down"></i>
                </a>
                <ul>
                   <li><a href="#">Two #1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Two #2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Two #3</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>


            <li>
                <a href="#">
                    Three
                    <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-down"></i>
                </a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Three #1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Three #2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Three #3</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>


            <li>
                <a href="#">
                    Four
                    <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-down"></i>
                </a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">#1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">#2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">#3</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">#4</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>


            <li>
                <a href="#">
                    Five
                    <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-down"></i>
                </a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Five #1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Five #2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Five #3</a></li>

                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <h1> ghjgjh ftfytf fytftyt drdtr rdetrert retretr ee45e ertetr rdrttr retret tdret </h1>
     <h1> ghjgjh ftfytf fytftyt drdtr rdetrert retretr ee45e ertetr rdrttr retret tdret </h1>
    <h1> ghjgjh ftfytf fytftyt drdtr rdetrert retretr ee45e ertetr rdrttr retret tdret </h1>
    <h1> ghjgjh ftfytf fytftyt drdtr rdetrert retretr ee45e ertetr rdrttr retret tdret </h1>


</body>
</html>
```

css

```
.nav {
  width:900px;
  margin: 0 auto}

ul{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type:none;
 text-align:center;}


ul li{
  float:left;
  width:180px;}






li ul{  display:none;}

li:hover ul{
  display:block;}




ul li a{
  display:block;
  padding: 5px 15px 5px 15px;
  background:#69F;
  color:#ffffff;

  border-top: 1px solid #FFF;
  margin-left:1px;}



ul li a:hover{
  background:#F80;
  color:#fff}


h1 {
clear:both;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because the navbar itself is growing in height. If you want the navbar to overlap the content, look into z-index and absolute display.

```
li:hover ul{
  position:absolute;
  z-index: 10; //can be any number higher than the content's z-index.
  width: 180px; //This controls the size of the dropdowns container
  display:block;
}
```

Comment: it works when add to the second ul (position absulte) but the sub li didn't render vertically

Answer (score 0):

Your sub-menu needs to be set to position absolute and your parent LI needs to be set to position relative. You should set visibility to hidden and then show it for :hover. This method will not push down content.

Also, you need to make sure that you set a width to the ul li ul <--- submenu.